# Yii2-user Dektrium - how to hash password

Tags: yii2, yii2-extension

i  want to do hash password and check that with database ( password_hash )
How can I do it????

```
        $username = $auth['username'];
```

my password is

```
 $password = $auth['password'];
```

i want hash that :

```
 $find = \dektrium\user\models\User::findOne(['username' => $username, 'password_hash' => $password]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate the $hash using

```
$hash = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($password);


$find = \dektrium\user\models\User::findOne(['username' => $username, 
      'password_hash' => $hash]);
```

Th code belowe is from  dektrium/yii2-user/helpers/password.php  ( the code for hash function ..of dektrium adn as you see  the extensions use the generatePasswordHash and a cost

```
public static function hash($password)
{
    return \Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password,
      \Yii::$app->getModule('user')->cost);
}
```

default cost  = 8

Comment: that is not true ! this plugin use another way to hash password @ScaisEdge

Comment: @Saltern   . dektrium  Yii2-user  is na extension ..(not a plug-in) .. answer  updated  witha brief  suggestion ... hope is clear  .. for you...

Comment: is cost changing every time?
because i hash password with this way and that is not work

Comment: i don't know  if you have another cost .. assigned .. (but don't should change very time  .. should be fixed  .. )   and  \Yii::$app->getModule('user')->cost  should return you local cost .. assigned

Comment: this is my password in database : $2y$10$GnyZzQh4PJox8J7Dn6LX2.TU6JSXJhtyd/99i3IyXzpV70w6wVK42
and this is my password createed by your code :
$2y$10$zD98.lx7/8dD4cZkbBspV.iD.X9ensd6q/Qvu2veSuNmtQjQIkKsm


Why are different from each other?

Comment: I don't know why are different .. try create a new one and test if you have  the same problem ..

Comment: i try for check new record but has different  with together !

Comment: which cost return   \Yii::$app->getModule('user')->cost?

Comment: ````return ->       10

Comment: yes! It seems password save  and check at database with another way!

Comment: Have you looked  at how the login retrive a valid  user access ?? this could be useful

Comment: statrt from   .. vendor/dektrium/ ... /controller/SecurityController  actionLogin   ...but looking to vendor/dektrium/model/User .. in beforeSave you can see that tha hash in managed  without key ...  .and last  could be you need  a debugging tracing ... of the code ... (not easy )

Comment: Why a password  hashed each time is a different thing????
every time i refrash page i get a diffrent result!!!!

Comment: Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $password_hash);

Comment: what do you mean with the last comment ?

Comment: Password Every time something was encrypted . and can only checking with this function  !

Comment: Ok ... thanks  .. then  you must use this tecnique for   filter ..the user. I understand .. .. however I hope my suggestions may have been useful

Comment: yes i select password hashed only where with username and validate password with this function ! thank u for every things.

Answer (score 0):

I know quite late to answer this, but for those who are still looking.. I recently encountered this issue and after lots of testing below code worked for me:

```
$behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
        'auth' => function ($username, $password) {
            $user = \dektrium\user\models\User::findOne(['username' => $username]);
            if ($user->validate($password)) {
                return $user;
            }
            return null;
        }
    ];
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please add some details about how this is a good answer to solve the problem, instead of just saying it solves the problem?